# How long does it take a starving zombie to become a Romero?

Tags: izombie-2015

In the series "iZombie," zombified people who don't get a regular diet of grey matter eventually become mindless, savage creatures lovingly referred to as "Romeros." Was it ever established how long it takes for this transformation to occur?

Comment: It's only a matter of days. I don't remember a hard period, but it's less than a week.